# Verifying a proof regarding the duals of two equivalent compound propositions also being equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

I am aware that there are many previously asked questions regarding the proof that the duals of two equivalent compound propositions containing only logical operators  ∨, ∧, and ¬ are also equivalent, although I have not yet been content with the solutions I have found.

If possible, I would like someone qualified to see if I am on the right track with my current proof of the above. Please note that I am only at a relatively basic level for proof-writing, although I wish to advance this whenever possible.

Below is a definition of the *dual* of a compound proposition containing only logical operators ∨, ∧, and ¬, found in *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*, 7th Edition, by Rosen, followed by the relevant theorem and current draft of my proof.

> The **dual** of a compound proposition that contains only the
>   logical operators ∨, ∧, and ¬ is the compound proposition
>   obtained by replacing each ∨ by ∧, each ∧ by ∨, each **T**
>   by **F**, and each **F** by **T**. The dual of *s* is denoted by *s∗*.

> **Theorem:**
>   The duals of two equivalent compound propositions are also equivalent.
>
> **Proof:**
>   Let $s_0$, $s_n$ be two arbitrary compound propositions containing
>   only logical operators ∨, ∧, or ¬, such that $s_0$ $\equiv$ $s_n$
>   after transforming $s_0$ with *n* logical equivalences containing
>   only logical operators ∨, ∧, or ¬.
>
> Let $t_0$, $t_1$, $\ldots$ , *t*<sub>*n-1*</sub> be an ordered sequence of
>   *n* transformations using logical equivalences only containing the ∨, ∧,
>   or ¬ operators such that $t_i$($s_i$) = *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>, for 0 $\leq$
>   i $\leq$ n-1, where $s_i$, *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub> are compound propositions, and let
>   $s_0^*$, $s_1^*$, $\ldots$ , $s_n^*$ be the
>   corresponding duals for $s_0$, $s_1$, $\ldots$ , $s_n$, respectively.
>
> We wish to find an ordered list of *m* transformations, $t_0^*$, $t_1^*$,
>   $\ldots$ , *t*<sub>*m-1*</sub>$^*$ such that $t_i^*$($s_i^*$) =
>   s<sub>i+1</sub>$^*$,
> for 0 $\leq$ i $\leq$ *m*-1, where $s_i$,
>   *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub> are compound propositions.
>
> Since every logical equivalence for a compound proposition containing only 
>   the ∨, ∧, or ¬ operators has a *dual equivalent*, that is, a complementary
>   logical equivalence for the dual of the compound proposition, we let the
>   logical equivalence transformation $t_i^*$ be the dual equivalent of the
>   transformation $t_i$ when the transformation is performed on a compound
>   proposition, and otherwise the same transformation when performed on an
>   individual element,
>  for 0 $\leq$ i $\leq$ *n*-1.
>
> Thus, $t_i^*$($s_i^*$) = *s*<sub>*i+1*</sub>$^*$, for 0 $\leq$ i $\leq$ *n*-1,
>   is a valid ordered sequence of logical equivalence transformations, and $s_0^*$
>   $\equiv$ $s_n^*$. Since $s_0^*$ and $s_n^*$ were chosen to be arbitrary,
>   true for all such.
>
> *End of proof.*

I feel that the first statement in last paragraph of my proof is not explicit enough, although I am not currently able to think of what is additionally needed.

Please help if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.